# Как настроить ассеты?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При установке рэилз приложения на сервер возникла проблема: ассеты компилируются в один большой файл, а хэдер пытается подключить их по отдельности. На локальнике все файлы подключаются раздельно, и проблем не возникает. Где это может настраиваться?

Comment: может быть здесь найдете ответ http://rails.hasbrains.org/screencasts/49

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в environment.rb либо production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(file1.js file2.js file3.css file4.css)
```

Comment: Я помру все файлы добавлять, это не выход... И я в девелопмент а не в продакшен запускаю.

Comment: Темболее что компилировать-то он их компилирует, но в один большой файл просто.

Comment: Значит вы что-то делаете неправильно. Assets предназначены именно для того, чтобы собирать все файлы в один и подключать его.

Comment: Я и пытаюсь выяснить, что я делаю не так.
 
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Вот подключение, но оно компилируется в подключение всех файлов отдельно, а не подключает этот большой файл почему-то

Answer (score 0):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(.html .erb .haml
        .css .js .png .gif .jpg .jpeg
        .svg .woff .woff2 .eot .ttf)
```

Думаю, этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то всё работает, как и задумано.
В девелопменте ваш `javascript_include_tag 'application'` превращается в серию индивидуальных `<script>` для удобства дебаггинга. В продакшене он же превращается в один минифицированный скрипт.

Что именно не работает и как?